# How do I disable some chrome extensions but still keep their icons in the bar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I don't want some extensions running all the time taking up all my RAM but I don't want to have to enable them from the extensions page all the time. Anyway to disable them but keep their icon in the bar for quick reenable?

Comment: what you are asking for is more like  having a cake and eating it too

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't either they are running or they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Well I decided to install the Extensions Button which leaves them just one extra click away.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbacmcchkmlgbbnkjbdgepkegjblhaog